# Is there an easy way to make a collapsible QWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

Often on web pages, there are whole areas that contain content that can be reduced to only the title. Is there a way to achieve the same with a `QWidget`?

For a very simple example of this functionality, see the screenshots [here](http://wordpress.org/plugins/collapsible-widget-area/screenshots/). Of course, the contents should be any `QLayout`, and thus arbitrary.

Comment: I think you can can get away with using a `QTreeWidget` and using styling to make it look how you want. As far as I know, that's how they make the similar widget in Qt designer.

Comment: Will the "Dynamic Layout Example" (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layouts-dynamiclayouts.html) help in creation of something that could be collapsed/expanded?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `QToolBox` widget:

[image: QToolBox screenshot]